# What are the units of measure/ dimensions of given edge attributes in Osmnx

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

my question is rather simple: osmnx allows you to get the length of the edges of a given place. **What are the units of measure of the length attribute?** (km or meters).

Also this operation **`osmnx.speed.add_edge_travel_times(G)`** gives me the time it takes to go through an edge at a given speed (which has to be set as km/h). Again, **what are the units of measure of these time intervals?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All units are documented in the functions' [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.speed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance unit used internally are *meters*. You can check for instance with the function that adds the edge lengths,[`osmnx.utils_graph.add_edge_lengths(G)`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.add_edge_lengths), which as mentioned considers the specified lengths to be in meters.

And [`osmnx.speed.add_edge_travel_times`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.add_edge_lengths) is used to add edge travel times *in seconds*. This, as mentioned in the docs, is based on `length` and `speed_kph` attributes, which must be set prior to setting the edge travel times. So even though the speeds are set in *km/h* the base time unit that is used are seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much!